# SQL Server - CTE and Delete in a VIEW

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Trying to create a VIEW that starts with adding rows of customers into a CTE, deletes some customer that matches certain criteria from the CTE and then does a final SELECT.  Getting the following error right before the delete statement:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vwUpForRN, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Delete'

SQL:

```
ALTER VIEW vwUpForRN
AS
    WITH UpForRN ([CustomerID]
          ,[ContractStartDate]
          ,[ContractEndDate]      
          ,[PlanName]
          ,[ProductID]
          ,[ContractTimeline]) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            [CustomerID],
            [ContractStartDate],
            [ContractEndDate],
            [PlanName],
            [ProductID],
            [ContractTimeline]
        FROM 
            [Reporting].[Customer].[vwContracts]
        WHERE 
            ContractCategory = 'Regular'
            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), ContractEndDate) <= 60
            AND ContractTimeline <> 'Past'
    )
    DELETE FROM UpForRN 
    WHERE ContractTimeline = 'Future'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Most do not support `delete` in a view, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want the CTE.  So your code would be:

```
ALTER VIEW vwUpForRN AS
    SELECT [CustomerID], [ContractStartDate], [ContractEndDate], [PlanName], [ProductID], [ContractTimeline]
    FROM [Reporting].[Customer].[vwContracts]
    WHERE ContractCategory = 'Regular' AND
          DateDiff(day,getdate(), ContractEndDate) <= 60 AND
          ContractTimeline NOT IN ('Past', 'Future');
```

That is, you don't delete from a view.  You just don't put those rows in to begin with.

Comment: Since the OP wants to "delete" (or exclude) rows from the view where `ContractTimeline = 'Future'` I would think the last line of your query should be `ContractTimeline <> 'Past' AND ContractTimeline <> 'Future';`. I guess that leaves `'Now'`.

Comment: @HABO . . . Your comment elucidated what the OP is trying to do.  That makes the question a bit clearer.